# How to call async/await method without using GlobalScope.launch{} in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, okhttp

I am trying to use async/await in kotlin to make calls to an api. I already created the method and it works! but now I don't know how to call it in an activity or in a viewmodel WITHOUT using GlobalScope.launch {} ?? There is another way ?

```
class Service{
    var client: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient();
     fun getRequest(sUrl: String) =GlobalScope.async {
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        var result: String? = null
        try {
            // Create URL
            val url = URL(sUrl)
            // Build request
            val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
            // Execute request
            val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
            result = response.body?.string()
        }
        catch(err:Error) {
            print("Error when executing get request: "+err.localizedMessage)
        }
        return@async result
    }
}
```

Comment: Make your method suspend then use a viewmodel's viewModelScope or an Activity's lifcycleScope to call the suspend method.

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you can also use [runBlocking](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/guide) or [newSingleThreadContext](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/jvm/test/guide/example-context-04.kt) or similar.